# Form validation in select field

Tags: php, laravel, forms, validation

Is there a way I can check if a user didn't manipulate the form? In my form, I get all available entries, but if a user changes the value id in the browser, I would just get an error. Any tips:)?

```
<div class="form-group-row club col-lg-10">
    <label>Choose Product</label>
    <select name="product_id" class="form-control" required>
    @foreach($products as $product)
        <option value="{{$product->id}}">{{$product-> product}}</option>
    @endforeach
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: What about Form Request validation? https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a Rule to validate the received data like :

```
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

Validator::make($data, [
    'product_id' => [
        'required',
        Rule::in([/*array of products ids here*/]),
    ],
]);
```

Take a look at https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#rule-in

You could use exists like :

```
Validator::make($data, [
    'product_id' => [
        'required',
        'exists:table_name,column_name'
    ],
]);
```

Comment: or using the `exists` rule on the `products` table or whatever table?

Comment: the thing is, a user can create more categories if he wants. But I will read the documentation. tyvm :)

Comment: Create them and use them at the same time will create a problem, but if they're stored in the database then you can read them in `[/*array of products ids here*/]` part

Answer (score 0):

you can do select readonly

```
<select name="product_id" class="form-control" required readonly>
```

but user can change html by devtools

also you can check it on backend side like this

```
if ($products->pluck('id')->diff(request()->input('product_id'))->empty()) {
    //not changed
}
```

Comment: You should read about better way of validating a request https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation